# How do I execute ps script in XML

Tags: xml, powershell, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have one PS script that need to be execute/invoke via XML.  getting error like

$sessions = Get-RDUserSession  foreach($session in $sessions){Invoke- ...

Unexpected token 'in' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:78
$sessions = Get-RDUserSession  foreach($session in $sessions){Invoke- ...
Missing closing ')' in expression.
At line:1 char:109

**config.xml**

```
<Action name="KillAllUsers" Type="Powershell" Executor='$sessions = Get-RDUserSession
foreach ( $session in $sessions ) 
{ Invoke-RDUserLogoff -HostServer $session.HostServer -UnifiedSessionID $session.UnifiedSessionId -Force }'></Action>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Literal*<sup>[1]</sup> newlines (line breaks) in XML *attributes* of XML *text*** are seemingly *not* preserved when XML text is parsed into a [DOM (Document Object Model)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model); they are **replaced with *spaces***.

Therefore, whatever code you put in your `Executor` attribute ends up as a *single line*, which is why you must `;`, PowerShell's statement separator, to separate your statements; note the `;` after `Get-RDUserSession` and note that the line breaks are purely for readability here:

```xml
<Action name="KillAllUsers" Type="Powershell" Executor='
$sessions = Get-RDUserSession;
foreach ( $session in $sessions ) { 
  Invoke-RDUserLogoff -HostServer $session.HostServer -UnifiedSessionID $session.UnifiedSessionId -Force
}
'></Action>
```

---

As for the error you saw:

Due to your code being placed all on a single line without statement separators, the `foreach` statement syntactically became an *argument* to the `Get-RDUserSession` command, which caused a syntax error; a simple way to provoke the error is:

```bash
# -> ERROR: "Unexpected token 'in' in expression or statement."
Get-Date foreach ($i in 1..2) { $i }
```

---

<sup>[1] By contrast, ***escaped* line breaks** (`&#xA;` for LF-only newlines, `&#xD;&#xA;` for CRLF newlines) *are* preserved: they are converted to *literal* newlines *in memory* (in the DOM), and reconverted to their *escaped* form during serialization, i.e. when converting the in-memory DOM to a *string* or saving it to a *file*.</sup>

Comment: Thanks, I have past that error but getting something different error now.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Willingtolearn. As for a different error: unless it is a simple thing that can quickly be resolved in the comments here, I suggest creating a _new_ question post.

Comment: thank you very much. I am not sure, if its a easy fix but I can create a new post :) A Remote Desktop Services deployment does not exist on 
server. This operation can be performed after creating a 
 deployment. For information about creating a deployment, run "Get-Help 
 New-RDVirtualDesktopDeployment" or "Get-Help New-RDSessionDeployment".